# Deleting file from device after using [NSData writeToFile:]

Tags: ios, nsdata, writetofile

In my code I'm doing:

```
[anNsDataObject writeToFile:@"thefile" atomically:YES];
```

How can I delete this file from my device?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `NSFileManager`'s [`removeItemAtPath:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW18) method.

Example:

```
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:@"theFile" error:&error];

if (error)
{
  // file deletion failed
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to ensure ```removeItemAtPath``` happens synchronously? I have read that ```NSFileManager``` may or may not delete the file depending on data storage and other factors.